# theorem connecting bounded and limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, analysis

[image]

I can see II is correct by drawing graphs. Is there a theorem that says in R, if f(x) is bounded below and decreases, then it has a limit at infinity? Is monotonic bounded sequence must converge applying here? Thank you!

Comment: I is not true because $f$ may take arbitrary positive values at countably many values of $x$ with no change to the integral. II is true and in fact $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$. III I will have to think about.

Comment: @Math1000...of $III$,as a counterexample, how about  we take a function which is zero except some infinitely smooth  bumps(very far apart one from the other) where in each bump $max{f(x)}=1$ and the bumps shrink in width with area $\frac{1}{n^2}$??

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer.

The first one is not true.

Take $f(x)=n$ if $x=n \in \Bbb{N}$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

The second is true since the decreasing function converges to $L=\inf\{f(x):x>1\}$

Comment: How do you know $\int_1^{\infty}\sin^2(x^2)$ converges?

Comment: @ Marios could you please argue rigorously why II is true? Thank you!

Comment: I made a mistake..only the integral of $sin(x^a)$ convergens,bu the funtion is not non-negative